# Exoplayer stuck after swiching Stream

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm using the following code to play a m3u8 file:

```
    SimpleExoPlayerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(this);
    simpleExoPlayerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);

    simpleExoPlayerView.setUseController(false);
    simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();
    simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://.../playlist.m3u8");

    DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeterA = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "exoplayer2example"), bandwidthMeterA);


    MediaSource videoSource = new HlsMediaSource(uri, dataSourceFactory, 1, null, null);

    player.setPlayWhenReady(true); //run file/link when ready to play.
    player.setVideoDebugListener(this); //for listening to resolution change and  outputing the resolution

    player.setVolume(1);

    player.prepare(videoSource);
    player.addListener(this);
```

Now i change the Quality of the Video by button click:

```
    Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MappingTrackSelector.MappedTrackInfo mappedTrackInfo = trackSelector.getCurrentMappedTrackInfo();
            MappingTrackSelector.SelectionOverride override;
            TrackSelection.Factory FIXED_FACTORY = new FixedTrackSelection.Factory();
            for(int y = 0; y < mappedTrackInfo.length; y++) {
                TrackGroupArray tracks =  mappedTrackInfo.getTrackGroups(y);
                for(int i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
                    TrackGroup trackGroup = tracks.get(i);
                    for(int x = 0; x < trackGroup.length; x++) {
                        Format format = trackGroup.getFormat(x);
                        int width = format.width;
                        if (width == 1280) {
                            override = new MappingTrackSelector.SelectionOverride(FIXED_FACTORY, i, x);
                            trackSelector.setSelectionOverride(y, tracks, override);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

After changing the video stucks for a few seconds an then there is a hard cut and the better streamquality is visible.

fine. but how can i get this more smooth like it is on netflix?
Here is my Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.7.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.7.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.7.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.7.3'
```

Thanks,
phil